# Display input value depending on select

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a result in an input box depending on a select.

So, if "1" is select the input will show "one" and if "2" is selected the input will show "two".

My code below will not allow to select "2" as an option.

```js
function SelectData(data) {

  if (data.value = "1") {
    document.getElementById("result").value = "one";
  } else if (data.value = "2") {
    document.getElementById("result").value = "two";
  }

}
```

```html
<select onchange="SelectData(this)">
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>

<input id="result" disabled>
```

Can anyone help?

Many thanks,

John

Comment: use Comparison Operators(==) instade of Assignment Operators(=) in if else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator in your if/else if statements. `=` will set a variable to a value, `==` will check if a variable equals a value.

There is also another operator, `===` which acts type-specific:

- `"1" == true` will evaluate to `true`
- `"1" === true` will evaluate to `false`

whereas

- `1 === 1` or `true === true` will evaluate to `true` again.

```js
function SelectData(data) {

if (data.value == "1") {
document.getElementById ("result").value = "one";
}

else if (data.value == "2") {
document.getElementById ("result").value = "two";
}

}
```

```html
<select onchange="SelectData(this)">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
</select>

<input id="result" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `==` not `=`

`data.value == "1"` ask if the value is `equal` 1

`data.value = "1"` set the value to 1

```js
function SelectData(data) {

  if (data.value == "1") {
    document.getElementById("result").value = "one";
  } else if (data.value == "2") {
    document.getElementById("result").value = "two";
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="SelectData(this)">
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>

<input id="result" disabled>
```